# MBHUDprogress bar plus ASIHTTPRequest for tracking download

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using ASIHttpRequest and MB-HUD-progress library now i want to display MBHUD progress bar to downloading video file.
I am confuse this documentation of both library.they are not sufficient for beginners.

This is my code I am using In app purchase libs. I don't know how can u implement below methods of ASSiHttpRequest to tract my download with both library

```
- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
 {
NSLog(@"Transaction Completed");
// You can create a method to record the transaction.
// [self recordTransaction: transaction];

// You should make the update to your app based on what was purchased and inform user.
// [self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

// Finally, remove the transaction from the payment queue.

HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:HUD];

// Set determinate mode
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
//HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Downloading";

// myProgressTask uses the HUD instance to update progress
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myProgressTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

[self downloadFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"]];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    }

   -(void)downloadFromURL:(NSURL *)url
     {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"small.mp4"];
  NSLog(@"Path is %@",filePath);
  [request setDelegate:self];
  [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
  [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
  [request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
  [request startAsynchronous];
  [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
   request.showAccurateProgress = YES;
  }


    - (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request incrementDownloadSizeBy:(long long)newLength
   {
    NSLog(@"newLength: %lld", newLength);
     }

    -(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes {
    NSLog(@"Received bytes:%lld",bytes);

       }

     -(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

   {
 [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
 [self movieReceived];

    }

    -(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
     { 

NSLog(@"%@",request.error);

    }


   -(void)movieReceived
      {
    playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
     }


 - (void)myProgressTask {
// This just increases the progress indicator in a loop
float progress = 0.0f;
while (progress < 1.0f) {
    progress += 0.01f;
    HUD.progress = progress;
    usleep(60000);
}
     }
```

I dont know how can i change all the Value of myprogresstask to update progress bar according to the file size..

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you use progress bar for downloading purposes embedded in ASIHTTPReaquest.

Comment: I dont know that there is built in progress bar for ASIHTTPRequest...but MBHUDProgress bar is stylish and looks good so i used MBHUDprogress bar

Comment: Ofcourse progress bar is there.Find my answer in comment,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the percentage of bytes received against total bytes in

`-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes`

and set the progress value

`HUD.progress = normalisedPercentage;`

Comment: what if file size is unknown ..than how can i calculate it

Comment: Then you can't show progress. How will you show progress if you don't know what size you are downloading.

Comment: I thought there will be some methods by using which we can display progress bar...if we know file size than what should i need to  do??..didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes in this method what shoul di do with byte?..should i add them into one another byte variable and check if it is equal to my file size and according to that add percentage to HUD.progress??..can you please edit your answer in brief please

Comment: the method doesn't return the bytes itself. It returns the amount of bytes received. So divide bytes received by total bytes and set it progress.

Comment: i tried this but at this code progressbar display and hide 
-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes {
    NSLog(@"Received bytes:%lld",bytes);
    progress = 0.0f;
 if (progress < 1.0f) {
        
        progress = ((float)bytes) / 469690;
        NSLog(@"progress value is %f",progress);
        
  HUD.progress = progress;
    }
}

Comment: Is there any problem in my method or didreceiveBytes

Comment: its correct. as long as the value between 0 and 1 your progress view should show properly.

Comment: yes i divide by total number of size than assign it to progress variable and than variable assign to HUD.progress. but my progress bar hide with in second and i can see in log that bytes are downloading after that..

Answer (score 1):

Showing Progress bar for downloading.

```
ASINetworkQueue *requestUserSpecificFileQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue reset];
UIProgressView *progressView=[[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 190, 200, 20)];
[ViewSelected addSubview:progressView];
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(downLoadFinished:)];
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(downloadFailed:)];
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue setDelegate:self];
ASIHTTPRequest *requestUserSpecificFile=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[dict objectForKey:@"object"]];
requestUserSpecificFile.tag=bookViewSelected.tag;
[requestUserSpecificFile setDownloadDestinationPath:[[self returnUnzipBundlePathName] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dictLocal[@"fullLengthFilename"]]];
```

## if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0

```
[requestUserSpecificFile setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

## endif

```
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue addOperation:requestUserSpecificFile];
[requestUserSpecificFileQueue go];
```

Comment: can you please tell me where should i put my URL in asiNetworkQueue?..because i have used ASIHTTPRequest for url downloading..and you are using network queue..

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest *requestUserSpecificFile=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[dict objectForKey:@"object"]];
    requestUserSpecificFile.tag=bookViewSelected.tag;
    [requestUserSpecificFile setDownloadDestinationPath:[[self returnUnzipBundlePathName] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dictLocal[@"fullLengthFilename"]]];
    
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
    [requestUserSpecificFile setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
#endif
    [requestUserSpecificFileQueue addOperation:requestUserSpecificFile];
    [requestUserSpecificFileQueue go]; Use this code for URL.

Comment: thanks for help..it work but do you have any other stylish progress bar.